# Hortonworks Data Platform 2.4 (Sandbox): Directory structure

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, hortonworks-data-platform

I downloaded and started an instance of the HDP 2.4 as a VMWare sandbox. I just had a look for the directory structure, and found the there are the following 2 folders:

- /usr/hdp/2.4.0.0-169
- /usr/hdp/current

Why do I have two folders here as I didn't make any updates yet. I guess that the `current` folder is used for the platform tools like Spark etc. So if I need to update one of them (e.g. Spark) do I have to make the "changes" to that `current` folder or on both? Or will an update work completely different? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/usr/hdp/current contains symlinks to versioned directories i.e. /usr/hdp/current points to /usr/hdp/2.4.0.0-169

Comment: So, if I upgrade HDP from e.g. 2.3.x to 2.4.x, I can delete the /usr/hdp/2.3.x folder because I only need the two folders "2.4.x" (installation files) and "current" (links)?